# Find a point on $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$ such that $y'=16$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm very new in this forum and I hope I don't ask something silly, which is asked many times before.

I have to answer this question:

> Find the coordinates of the point(s) at which the curve has the specified gradient.
>
> (c) $y=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$, gradient = $16$

My solution is the point $(-0.5,4)$, but the textbook solution is $-(-0.5,4)$.

Why is there a minus in front of the point in the textbook solution?

Comment: I've never seen the notation $-(x,y)$ referring to points on a graph. I'll bet it is just an error in the textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there **isn't** "a minus in front of the point", because the negation of a point has no meaning.  It probably is a "hyphen".

Comment: It probably is a mistake in the answer. I just wanted to make sure, if it is possible to have a minus in front of a point and what it would mean.